Strange noise from smallest cog
I have just replaced bottom bracket bearings, chainring, chain, and rear cassette, (7-speed) with decent Shimano bits and when in the highest gear i.e., big front cog smallest rear cog, I get a dull whirring as if something is mis-aligned. Im wondering whether I should alter position of crankwheel by unscrewing the bottom bracket cartridge a bit?

I think we will need a little more information. But don’t loosen the bottom bracket!  You run the risk of damaging your frame (the bottom bracket shell) drone the movement that will occur when riding with a loose bottom bracket.

Do you suspect the BB is further sideways than it was originally?  Do you have a way to support the bike while you hand-pedal it and look for the source of noise closer ?

Is the derailleur properly adjusted? Especially the limit screw. The smallest cog (usually 11 teeth) can sometimes be a bit noisy and cause some vibrations at high speeds. I think that’s just because it’s rotating fastest for a given crankset cadence. Maybe also because from an engineering perspective it’s probably somewhat close to how small you can make a sprocket (there are 9t sprockets, but I really wonder what their efficiency and noise levels are like).

I'm pretty certain you shouldn't adjust the BB.
It's much more likely that the little cog was slightly worn to the old chain, and the new chain isn't running nicely on it.  The noise is indistinguishable.  This is more noticeable on smaller cogs with fewer teeth engaged, than on bigger ones; wear depends both on frequency of use and on cog size, so if you spend a lot of time in the smallest cog that' pretty much the worst case
